# Keep node with lowest value

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying work on simple things,however as I'm new in xslt I stuck with below:
Could you advise please? How to keep only id with lowest price
my xml:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <id>LT00</id>
        <price>1600</price>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>LT00</id>
        <price>350</price>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>XL50</id>
        <price>500</price>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>XL50</id>
        <price>800</price>
    </item>    
</items>
```

Expexted outcome:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <id>LT00</id>
        <price>350</price>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>XL50</id>
        <price>500</price>
    </item> 
</item>
```

my xslt:

`

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <items>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="items/item/id" group-by="id" order="ascending" data-type="number">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group( )"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>

        <xsl:for-each select="current-group( )">
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current()" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </items>   

</xsl:template>
```

`

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using? Also, please show your attempted XSLT code, even if it does not work.

Comment: You need to group on `id` and sort the groups on `price` to take the first or lowest in each group.

Comment: I'm using version 1.0

Comment: I did as Martin suggested, and please see my xslt code above

Comment: @rkc, you say you use XSLT 1.0 but then post a sample with `for-each-group` which is XSLT 2.0. So please clarify which version you want to use.

Comment: sorry for delay, i could use actual both version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XSLT 2.0 you can use

```
<xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="id" >
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:sort select="number(price)"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>   
</xsl:template>
```

or as an alternative

```
<xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="id" >
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="id"/>
            <price><xsl:value-of select="min(current-group()/price)"/></price>
          </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>   
</xsl:template>
```

With XSLT 1.0 I would do it like this:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:key name="by-id" match="item" use="id"/>
<xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-id', id)[1])]">
          <xsl:for-each select="key('by-id', id)">
            <xsl:sort select="price" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>   
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: the code above is awesome, it works as i expected, thank you so much for your help, btw: thank you also for a good lesson as now I can see the difference between both versions

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:key match="item" name="grp" use="id"/>
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <root>
      <xsl:variable name="cur" select=".//item"/>
      <xsl:variable name="temp" select="item[count(.|key('grp',id)[1])=1]"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$temp">
        <xsl:variable name="temp1" select="id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="main">
          <xsl:for-each select="$cur[id=$temp1]">
            <xsl:sort select="price" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="msxsl:node-set($main)/*[1]"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Following works for XSLT-1.0. Do -note I have use node-set() function provided via .net to transform a variable into result fragment tree

I have used muenchian grouping to group together item nodes with same id values

```
<xsl:variable name="temp" select="item[count(.|key('grp',id)[1])=1]"/>
```

Then for each unique id, i found what are the item nodes with same id, sorted them in ascending order and then added to a variable.

Then the variable was converted to result tree fragment and the first item node was pushed to the xml.

Comment: thank you Saurav, the code is great, however i had some issue to implement this inside php :( now is sorted :)